# PHP CODE Saved in database needs to be run

Tags: php, eval

I have the blow code saved in database

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$url/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="$url/js/ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
```

I want to fetch this code from database and then assign it to a variable and then I want to use $url which is defined above in my code in file.

So here is the scenario

$url is defined in file example.php foreg $url = 'http://localhost';

fetch a piece of code from database (the code above)

assign it to a variable foreg $content = (code fetch from mysql is here)

and in the end $content should contain

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
```

This code is just an example code and I have totally different code but scenario is kinda same. Anyone can please help.

P.S And my code could contain url() (a custom function I created in another file.)

Comment: What have you tried? it's echoing out a string..Or are you talking about evaluating php code stored in database, as your title says?

Comment: Yes actually I want to evaluate my code by using eval() type of function. Unfortunately eval is not working. I have never used eval before but just heard of it

Comment: If you need to programmatically rely on eval() to build your page, there's something wrong in how you're doing things. Are you sure there's no other way? Did you considered a templating system?(dwoo,twig,smarty)

Comment: Let me tell you the scenario. I have a list of widgets. Only 1 widget can be enable at one time. I am using templatic wordpress theme and it needs to assign everything to $content in end to display certain things on certain area of page. At first I just put my code in file and assign it to the $content(the normal php way). But now my client needs to edit that code through wordpress admin panel. I thought of creating an admin option by saving that code in database and editing it. I am successfull in fetching the code and assigning it to $content but how ever I am not able to evaluate that code.

Comment: The code is of widgets which I created my self. It contain php and html.. Every widget has different code and I save that code in database. The html is code works good but the php is evaluating

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = str_replace('$url', 'http://localhost', $content);
```

Comment: No as I said its just an example code.. My code contain many variables like $url which defined across several files. so I need to use some kind of eval() functionality. and unfortunately eval is not working

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM MyCodeTable WHERE MyColumn = 'something'");

if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

    $content = str_replace('$url', $url, $row->code);
}
```

Notes: Ideally you wouldn't fetch your data from MySQL like this, but use another method like PDO instead. Also, like Seagull illustrated in his example, using `str_replace` is a safer way to do this rather than eval because you should not trust the data you store in your database.

Comment: But What if my code contain 45 different variables like $url ?

Comment: This example assumes that you are storing markup in your database (which is a bad thing to do, by the way). If you need to replace many things, then yes, it could become a tedious task, even though `str_replace` allows you to pass in arrays. It would surely be *easier* to use eval if this is the case.

Comment: If you are trying to use `eval` on all of the code, then I think that is your problem. It sounds as if `eval` is returning `FALSE` due to a parse error. I haven't actually used `eval` myself, but you will find an example on how to mix HTML and PHP with eval in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) (see the parameters section). Also, I would suggest that you do not store the markup in the database unless you have a very good reason to. Either just store script names and paths, for instance, or use files for this.

Comment: Thanks andy124 for the help :)